# Setting up server-side for GCM in an android app

Tags: android, facebook, server-side, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement push notifications in my app to notify when some new data is uploaded on a user subscribed facebook page.I'm going to use GCM for it.
I want to know how can i use the facebook api to implement the server side of the GCM.
Can i use the facebook server or resources itself as the server for my GCM?
If so please help me in doing it. 
(it is for an android app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. You should have your own server to do that. The implementation would go

Facebook updates <------ Request and response ---->Your Server

Your server<---- Request and response ---> GCM Server

Android Device <---- Request and response ---> GCM Server

Android Device -----> Generates broadcast receiver

For more information, refer http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: how can i set my server to receive facebook updates?

Comment: @ArsalanGundroo Well GCM is of no use here. Also you wont have to implement any server(unless you have some other plans). The only thing you can check out is if facebook api allows long polling or else you have to poll the data constantly for some interval time.